# Unable to use bootstrap-react modal in stateless function

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

What I want to do is add bootstrap-react modal and fire it from a stateless function. All the examples I can find requires changing the "show" in the state of component, but since Im not using af component I don't really have an idea how to do it.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/

You need `state` somewhere to show the modal. You can use hooks to do it in functional (not really "stateless") component using `useState`.

```
function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={open} onHide={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/z2ky5l128l

If you don't want to do it then you need to pass prop from component that is higher in tree, like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: true,
  }
  render() {
    return <ModalComponent open={open} hide={() => this.setState({open: false})} />
  }
}

function ModalComponent = ({open, hide}) => (
  <Modal show={open} onHide={hide}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      <Button variant="secondary" onClick={hide}>
        Close
      </Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
  </Modal>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass visible state from parrent like below

```
 class parent extends Component {

   state = {
     modalVisibility : false
   }

   handleModalVisibility = (action)=> this.setState({modalVisibility : action})

   return (
       <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleModalVisibility.bind(this,true)} >Show Modal</button>
       //use this props to show or cancel the modal
       <ModalComponent visibility ={this.state.modalVisibility} handleModal={this.handleModalVisibility} />
       </div>
   )

 }
```

Comment: you dont have to bind arrow functions

Comment: i am justing bind param true instead of writing onClick={()=>this.handleModalVisibility(true)}

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do that with useState
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html